# Plotting a Function With Noise

Tags: r, visualization, r-base-graphics

I always wondered how such pictures are made:

[image]

I am working with the R programming language. I would like to plot a parabola with "random noise" added to the parabola. I tried something like this:

```
x = 1:100
y = x^2
z = y + rnorm(1, 100,100)

plot(x,z)
```

[image]

But this is still producing a parabola without "noise".

Can someone please show me how I can add "noise" to a parabola (or any function) in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to generate 100 random points or will be adding the same amount of noise to each point (thus no noise).  z = y + rnorm(100, 100,100)

```
x = 1:100
y = x^2
z = y + rnorm(length(y), 100,100)

plot(x,z)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you add the same value to all your points so it just shifts your curve up by that constant. Instead you need to generate a vector of random noise the same length as your `y` variable. Also you probably want to set the `mean = 0` for the `rnorm()` noise so that it's truly random noise around the true value not systematically `100` units larger.

To get something very similar to your example, you can overplot the second vector with noise using `lines()` and add a legend with the code below.

```r
x = 1:100
y1 = x^2
y2 = y1 + rnorm(100, 0, 500)

plot(x, y1, type = "l", ylab = "y")
lines(x,y2,type = "l", col = "red")
legend(
  x = "top",
  legend = c("y1", "y2"),
  col = c("black", "red"),
  lwd = 1,
  bty = "n",
  horiz = T
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>